# SLD array-valued parameter example

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am writing a Rendering Transformation and would like to pass a parameter that is an array. The geoserver [documenation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implement-rendertrans.html#input-parameters) states that 
"Lists of values can be accepted by defining an array-valued parameter". Great, but how the heck does one properly define an array-valued parameter in SLD XML? An example would be great.

Below is an example SLD. I would like to make the parameter `computeArgs` be an array-valued parameter. What is the syntax?

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <NamedLayer>
  <Name>GeoHashGrid</Name>
  <UserStyle>
    <Title>GeoHashGrid</Title>
    <Abstract>GeoHashGrid aggregation</Abstract>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
      <Transformation>
        <ogc:Function name="vec:GeoHashGrid">
          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
            <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
            <ogc:Literal>gridStrategy</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>Metric</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
            <ogc:Literal>computeArgs</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>Please make me a list!!!</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
      </Transformation>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contour extraction takes an array of elevation values, see here for an example of how it's used:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#contour-extraction